# Column depended randomization of csv-data

Tags: python

I'm using a program called psychopy, it written in python, most of the time it has a GUI which is sufficient however you can input your own sections of code. Basically the problem i'm having is that I have a csv file which I get python to import, in the csv file there is six columns and with a bit of code I can get python to randomise the order in each column:

```
import random 
import csv 

stimulilist=list(csv.reader(open('original_file.csv',"rU")))

stimuliones=[]
locationones=[]
locationtwos=[]
stimulitwos=[]
locationthrees[]
locationfours[]

for i in range(len(stimulilist)):
    stimuliones.append(stimulilist[i][0])
    locationones.append(stimulilist[i][1])
    locationtwos.append(stimulilist[i][2])
    stimulitwos.append(stimulilist[i][3])
    locationthrees.append(stimulilist[i][4])
    locationfours.append(stimulilist[i][5])

Stim1=stimuliones[1:]
location1=locationones[1:]
location2=locationtwos[1:]
Stim2=stimuliones[1:]
location3=locationthrees[1:]
location4=positionfours[1:]
```

Then I randomize them, this will create my two randomized word lists for the first block of trials.

```
Stimuli1Random=random.sample(Stim1,len(Stim1)) 
Location1Random=random.sample(location1,len(location1))
Location2Random=random.sample(location2,len(location2))
Stimuli2Random=random.sample(Stim2,len(Stim2))
Location3random=random.sample(location3,len(location3))
Location4random=random.sample(location4,len(location4))
```

However, I want stimuli 1, location 1 and location 2 to be randomised together and stimuli 2 location 3 and location 4 to be randomised together for example:

How it is in CSV File:

```
(row)    Stim1 Location1 Location2         (row)     Stim2 Location3 Location4
1        P1    Left      Left               1        c1    Left      Left
2        p2    Middle    Middle             2        c2    Middle    Middle
3        p3    Right     Right              3        c3    Right     Right
4        p4    Left      Left               4        c4    Left      Left
5        p5    Middle    Middle             5        c5    Middle    Middle
6        p6    Right     Right              6        c6    Right     Right
```

With the code above each column gets randomised individually e.g.:

```
(row)    Stim1 Location1 Location2         (row)   Stim2  Location3 Location4
1        P6    Left      Middle             1      c5     Right     Left
2        p1    Right     Middle             2      c3     Middle    Middle
3        p5    Middle    Right              3      c1     Left      Middle
4        p4    Left      Left               4      c2     Right     Left
5        p3    Middle    Left               5      c4     Middle    Right
6        p2    Right     Right              6      c6     Left      Right
```

But I want the rows to be randomised so that it looks something like this:

```
(row)    Stim1 Location1 Location2       (row)  Stim2  Location3 Location4
1        p2    Middle    Middle           1     c3      Right   Right
2        p6    Right     Right            2     c5      Middle  Middle
3        p3    Right     Right            3     c4      Left    Left
4        p4    Left      Left             4     c1      Left    Left
5        p5    Middle    Middle           5     c2      Middle  Middle
6        P1    Left      Left             6     c6      Right   Right
```

So basically I want the rows for Stim1, Location 1 and Location 2 to stay the same but be randomised as if they were the same column, however, I do not want to merge them to one column, its important they stay individual columns. I also want this for stim2 location 3 and location 4.

Additionally, say I wanted to import another column from the csv file, but not randomise it, how would I put that into the code?

Comment: From your statement it sounds as if you are using the Builder of psychopy, is that right?

Comment: yes using the builder, but adding in code components.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomize these data parts together it would be easiest to store them together. You don't even have to change the structure of your csv-file for this. If you store the single parts together in a list (instead of every column on its own) you can then randomize this list and the relevant parts will stay together:

```
stimulilist=list(csv.reader(open('original_file.csv',"rU")))

stim_1_data = []
stim_2_data = []

for i in range(len(stimulilist)):
    stim_1_data.append(stimulilist[i][0:3])
    stim_2_data.append(stimulilist[i][3:6])

random.shuffle(stim_1_data)
random.shuffle(stim_2_data)
```

If you now want to get data for stim1 and stim2 you can just take one element from each list and separate the parts as you need them:

```
stim1, locaion1, location2 = stim_1_data.pop()
stim2, locaion3, location4 = stim_1_data.pop()
```

If you want another column from the csv file, just add another list that you don't randomize:

```
stimulilist=list(csv.reader(open('original_file.csv',"rU")))

stim_1_data = []
stim_2_data = []
non_random_data = []

for i in range(len(stimulilist)):
    stim_1_data.append(stimulilist[i][0:3])
    stim_2_data.append(stimulilist[i][3:6])
    non_random_data.append(stimulilist[i][6])

random.shuffle(stim_1_data)
random.shuffle(stim_2_data)
```

If you then need the lists the way you originally had the with each value seperate you can just extract them again:

```
Stim1, location1,location2 = zip(*stim_1_data)
Stim2, location3,location4 = zip(*stim_2_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it is really important that the columns stay separate - is there a way of randomising them, whilst keeping the parts together and whilst keeping them in their columns? Thank you for your help again :-)

Comment: Is there a special reason you need them in extra lists? To me it seems there is not much difference whether you store it this way or in separate lists. (But I'll post an alternative answer shortly)

Comment: Thanks again for your response. Yes there is a reason, it is quite hard to explain though, but basically the code above is used to create another csv file in which is then read and used by psychopy as my trial lists. But p1...nth has be displayed three times and in three locations (left, middle, right) the same for c1...nth. If they parts weren't together when randomised a stimulus could get displayed three times to the left etc. It's not just location there are a few other things that have to stay attached to each stimulus - not sure if this makes sense, hopefully it does

Comment: are you familiar with psychopy? If so, I have also have a different problem that has been troubling me for some quite some time that I just don't have the experience to solve, but someone who has a better experience with psychopy and python will probably be able to solve quite simply. I am big novice with python! Thanks again :-)

Comment: But the information does stay together. It's just stored in a list of tuples instead if three separate lists.

Comment: If you have another question best open another question.